# How to disable Lazy Preempt in kernel

Tags: kernel, vim, realtime

I'm relatively new to Linux and working on getting a real-time kernel up and running for robot applications. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, using kernel 3.14.3 and the 3.14.3-rt5 real-time patch. Also using x86-64.

There's a known error where the whole system crashes under some load when lazy preempt is enabled. This has happened to me a few times now. My question is:

How do I disable lazy preempt?

I read to add `NO_PREEMPT_LAZY` to the end of `/sys/kernel/debug/sched_features`, but when I try to do that (using `~$ sudo vim /sys/kernel/debug/sched_features`), upon trying to save and exit (`:wq`) I get the following error:

```
"/sys/kernel/debug/sched_features"
"/sys/kernel/debug/sched_features" E667: Fsync failed
WARNING: Original file may be lost or damaged
don't quit the editor until the file is successfully written!
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

If someone could help me get past the vim `Fsync failed` or disable lazy preempt in another way, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got [most of your answer somewhere else](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/disable-lazy-preempt-4175508405/). So editing files in [/sys/](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/multi/kernel_user_space_howto.html#toc2.3), specifically [debugfs](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/multi/kernel_user_space_howto-2.html#debugfs), this doesn't work because it's a pseudo-filesystem. The best way is to echo >> to files and do it as root since you are talking to the kernel directly. I can't tell if the code that implements the sched_features accepts that value. The [scheduler](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_121/opensuse-tuning/cha.tuning.taskscheduler.html) is quite [complex](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/kernel/169800-sched_features-tweaks.html).